Intuitively, why do F distributions not have a peak when df1 is 1 or 2?
In the context of the variance ratio F test, I'd like to understand intuitively why the F curves have no peak when the degree of freedom for the numerator variance is 1 or 2, but instead increase asymptotically as the F ratio goes to zero. The F curves for df > 2, with peaks in the vicinity of 1, seem intuitive, since if the null hypothesis is true, and the two samples are random samples from populations with equal variance, we'd expect the two sample variances to be approximately equal, giving a ratio of 1. But why would you ever expect F ratios close to zero under the null?
